# Filter topic by date

Tags: soql, rest-api, chatter, lightning-community, topics

From [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_topics_list.htm) for Experienced cloud site topic, It is clear that only two filters could be use.

How to use `query string` mentioned in doc to filter topics greater than some date? There is no example in doc as well to use that.
How to pass some criteria to filter topic list?

Comment: I tried `/services/data/v50.0/connect/communities/0DB7F000000CbHSWA0/topics/?q=SELECT+CreatedDate+FROM+Topic` but it dint return me any results

Comment: You can try something like  `/services/data/v50.0/query/?q=SELECT+CreatedDate+FROM+Topic+where+CreatedDate>2020-09-03T11:28:33.000Z` which will give results. Topics are not necessarily tied to Communities

Comment: Thanks @Swetha, i will try this out. Can we get the topics with above query associated with community as well something like `/connect/communities/communityId/topics`

Comment: @Swetha, your solution works, Thanks a lot ? Can we have updated field in the topic? I need to get the updated feeds

Comment: I tried to get FeedItem for topic via soql but could not get , it asks for ID field? Is that necessary ? Like can't we get list of feedItems greater than date